# Excluding a field in all values of a dictionary within a Pydantic model

Tags: python, pydantic

Is there any way to use the `__all__` identifier to exclude fields which are in all values of a dictionary field, the same way you can do for lists and tuples, as illustrated [here](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/exporting_models/#advanced-include-and-exclude), when exporting a Pydantic model.

Here is a toy example:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel


class ExampleValue(BaseModel):
    a: str
    b: str
    c: str


class Example(BaseModel):
    name: str
    list_field: list[ExampleValue]
    dictionary_field: dict[int, ExampleValue]


example = Example(
    name="example_1",
    list_field=[
        ExampleValue(a="a1", b="b1", c="c1"),
        ExampleValue(a="a2", b="b2", c="c2"),
        ExampleValue(a="a3", b="b3", c="c3"),
    ],
    dictionary_field={
        1: ExampleValue(a="a1", b="b1", c="c1"),
        2: ExampleValue(a="a2", b="b2", c="c2"),
        3: ExampleValue(a="a3", b="b3", c="c3"),
    },
)

print(
    example.json(
        indent=2,
        exclude={
            "list_field": {"__all__": {"c": True}},
            "dictionary_field": {"__all__": {"c": True}},
        },
    )
)
```

Output:

```json
{
  "name": "example_1",
  "list_field": [
    {
      "a": "a1",
      "b": "b1"
    },
    {
      "a": "a2",
      "b": "b2"
    },
    {
      "a": "a3",
      "b": "b3"
    }
  ],
  "dictionary_field": {
    "1": {
      "a": "a1",
      "b": "b1",
      "c": "c1"
    },
    "2": {
      "a": "a2",
      "b": "b2",
      "c": "c2"
    },
    "3": {
      "a": "a3",
      "b": "b3",
      "c": "c3"
    }
  }
}
```

P.S. I am using a dictionary within a Pydantic model (rather than nested models) because the key names are not known until runtime.

Comment: I've been trying for 2 days and am still unable to find a good solution for this.